# TypeORM: How to set one-to-one relationship on particular columns

Tags: nestjs, foreign-keys, typeorm, one-to-one

I have following entities (I have excluded unnecessary columns from the example):

```js
export class Products {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    external_id: number;
}

export class ProductDetails {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    description: string;

    @Column()
    external_id: number;
}
```

I would like to set proper 1:1 relationship between entities based on their external_id so that I could query either entity and get a whole result = a whole record joined on the foreign_id.

I believe I tried all possible ways of setting the OneToOne decorator as well as JoinColumn decorator but none of them worked out which means I obviously do something wrong.

Thanks in advance for your ideas!